# Approximating/Modeling A Section Of A Function

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I have a function that does not necessarily have an analytical solution, but I have been able to solve it numerically using Mathematica. But, I am only interested in a section of the function to study (its average, rms and minimum). Here is my problem in more detail:

Given the gaussian function:

[image]

I am interested evaluating the following function:
[image]

Where now I have f as a function of y. Using Mathematica I am able to numerically solve for f(y) and plot the function which is shown below:
[image]

Now, my issue is that I am ONLY interested in describing the negative 'dip' of f(y) (peaking t approximately y=0) and not at all interested in the positive peak in the +y direction.

So, I was wondering if there is any analytical manipulations I could do to lambda or f(y) to isolate and describe the negative 'dip' results?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $y$ and solve the derivative=0? (Not easy I suspect).

Comment: Do you want the value of $y$ at the dip, or do you want a function that also dips around the same place as your $f(y)$ and has approximately the same width?

Comment: I would like as much information as possible. Ideally, I would like an approximating analytical function that accurately describes the dip, only, as a function of y. The value of y is not of importance but the average, rms and minimum value of the dip are desired quantities.